# Aptana and GitLab version control using SSH

Tags: git, ssh, aptana, gitlab, aptana3

I am trying integrate Aptana on Windows with my local development server, which is running Ubuntu 14.10 with GitLab installed on it.  I am not an SSH pro and assume that this is the root of my problem, as is clearly an authentication issue.  I have Git Bash and Putty installed on my Aptana system, and have been able to set up SSH key that allow me to use Putty to connect to the server using a password-less login.  I have a private key generated by Putty, which is named 'key.ppk', and have exported that as an OpenSSH key as well, which is named 'key.openssh'.  I have also created a private key using Git Bash, which is simply a file named 'id_rsa' with no file extension.

In Aptana's Preferences under General > Network Connections > SSH2, I have the SSH2 Home Field set to my personal ssh folder (C:/Users/[me]/.ssh/), where all the above files are located.  In the Private Keys field, I have a comma separated list of the above private keys:

key.openssh,file.ppk,id_rsa

In GitLab, in my profile settings, I have added the public keys to my user account (both the id_rsa.pub key that was generated by Git Bash and key.pub, which was created by Putty).  To my limited understanding of SSH, my hope is that aptana is using all 3 private keys, and GitLab is using both public keys, and my assumption is that one of those combos should work.

When I try to push to the repository within Aptana, however, I am prompted:

"Please provide HTTP authentication password"

and prompts for a password for git@[my server].

I understand that the 'git' user account was created by the GitLab setup process, and that my successful logins using SSH in Putty and Git Bash are logging me in to my own user account rather than the git user account, so I think that is the root of my problem.  My SSH credentials are working for accessing my own user account, but does not work with the git user account.  In Putty, I can cause this same failure by setting the Auto-login username to 'git' and the authentication will fail, while if I leave the field blank or insert my account username on the server, I successfully log in.

I don't know whether this is the 'correct' behavior, and if so what I am doing wrong on my end to be able to SSH to the 'git' user account instead of my own.  Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong to get over what I hope is the 'last step' in what looks like a sweet development setup?

Answer (score 1):

Open the program "Git Bash" on your Windows machine and verify that you can ssh to your GitLab server, e.g., `ssh git@gitlab_server_hostname`. If it doesn't work then your private / public key setup has a problem.

When entering the GitLab project URI into Aptana, use the SSH version. It should look something like `git@gitlab_server_hostname:group/project.git`. From your error I'm guessing that you're trying to use the HTTP URL instead.

Try to do a Git operation through Aptana. If you get an SSH failure (publickey problems) then likely Aptana isn't finding your private key. Working through this is a pain but here are the [instructions](http://falahati.net/my-blog/98-aptana-and-git-through-ssh-problem). If you want to swing for the fences, for me I had to put my keys here:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Git\.ssh
```

After finding this, copy your current .ssh contents there and change your SSH2 home in the Aptana preferences to point at it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For me @mab's answer was helping.(I cant comment it that it helped me)

Especially the procedure in the mentioned link.
With this I figured out that the key hay to be in:

```
C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\com.aptana.portablegit.win32\.ssh\
```

and MUST be named id_rsa

Works fine now